# React Native: Prevent screen from being turned off

Tags: android, react-native

Our specialized hardware for our customers runs Android in a kiosk mode with our React native always on.

The app should always be running, with the display on, waiting for new orders to arrive. But I have noticed that sometimes our customers "accidentally" turn off the screen using the power button on the side of the device.

Is there some way to prevent the power button from being able to turn off the screen and app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using 'react-native-background-timer', that runs a small code in the background.

If the screen turns off using the power button, the background code identifies it, starts the screen and the app within five seconds.

Comment: and with what library did you start the screen again?

Answer (score 1):

If you are using expo managed app you should give a look into [KeepAwake](https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/sdk/keep-awake/)

**Installation** :

> expo install expo-keep-awake

**Example hook:**

```
import { useKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';

export default function KeepAwakeExample() {
  useKeepAwake();
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>This screen will never sleep!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Example functions:**

```
import { activateKeepAwake, deactivateKeepAwake } from 'expo-keep-awake';
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';

export default class KeepAwakeExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
        <Button onPress={this._activate} title="Activate" />
        <Button onPress={this._deactivate} title="Deactivate" />
      </View>
    );
  }

  _activate = () => {
    activateKeepAwake(); 
    alert('Activated!');
  };

  _deactivate = () => {
    deactivateKeepAwake(); 
    alert('Deactivated!');
  };
}
```

And for bare apps us [react-native-keep-awake](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake)

**Installation:**

> yarn add @sayem314/react-native-keep-awake

**Example hooks:**

```
import { useKeepAwake } from '@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
 
export default function KeepAwakeExample {
  useKeepAwake();
 
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <Text>This screen will never sleep!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Example components:**

```
import KeepAwake from '@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake';
import React from 'react';
import { Text, View } from 'react-native';
 
export default function KeepAwakeExample {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: 'center', justifyContent: 'center' }}>
      <KeepAwake />
      <Text>This screen will never sleep!</Text>
    </View>
  );
}
```

**Example functions:**

```
import { activateKeepAwake, deactivateKeepAwake} from "@sayem314/react-native-keep-awake";
import React from "react";
import { Button, View } from "react-native";
 
export default class KeepAwakeExample extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={{ flex: 1, alignItems: "center", justifyContent: "center" }}>
        <Button onPress={this._activate}>Activate</Button>
        <Button onPress={this._deactivate}>Deactivate</Button>
      </View>
    );
  }
 
  _activate = () => {
    activateKeepAwake();
  };
 
  _deactivate = () => {
    deactivateKeepAwake();
  };
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer!

But the issue remains for me after trying this. Cause it doesn't work if the user presses the power button right? That will still turn off the screen?

Comment: It will keep it alive if the user is idle but pressing power button is something else , i think it is not logical to prevent him from powering off his device

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do this only using React Native app, only Android OS can. Here's how to do it (you'll need to download a 3rd party app) :

Download Button Remapper from the Play Store, open it, turn on its accessibility right, go to button settings, tap on the power button option and click on none.
This will temporarily disable the power off button.

Comment: Thank you, I'm afraid that won't work though for us though. We already have a thousand devices deployed and we cant visit all customers and install this on their devices. Perhaps there is some way to work around this? Could we make the device wake up directly again after being put to sleep?

Comment: The only solution here is either installing this app, or develop the same accessibility function as Button Remapper, but the user will still need to go to settings and grant accessibility right to your app.
This is technically possible but will probably need some native code development.